# Session_destroy logs me out as admin, cant delete it

Tags: php, drupal

So this is a pickle. I am editing a Drupal site and I accidentally put session_destroy without initiating one. Now every time I want to fix this Drupal logs me out because it destroys the session (i.e. executes the page) when I try to save my changes. Any ideas?

Comment: edit the .php file you put this into, or whatever DB record the bad code's stored in?

Comment: I did. I took the session_destroy call off but when I click save, it tells me unauthorized. When I log in again, that destroy call is back again.

Comment: so you'll have to go rummaging around in the db and bypass drupal completely.

Comment: Any idea how to do this? I know it sounds simple, but I only took on this task to solve a minor php issue, I have a low understanding of how Drupal works.

Comment: no idea what drupal's innards look like. but somewhere there'll be a table/record that contains the code you've mucked up.

Comment: Doesnt look like I can do that from online admin space! I dont understand why Drupal executes the php in the pages when you edit them.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this is what I did to get out of this mess: I went to another page and executed an sql query that deleted the original corrupt php file. Problem solved.